# JSON as template: does not clear

Tags: python, json

I'm importing a JSON file and using it as a template over which I modify some of the properties.

```
with open('example.json') as data_file:
    j = json.load(data_file)
... # and within a loop:
    with open('output.json', 'w') as outfile:
        activejson = j # I would like this to reset or pull fresh from j
        ... # modify properties here
        json.dump(activejson, outfile, indent=4)
```

`activejson` isn't pulling the template `j` fresh through each iteration of the loop. (I'm able to pull old, modified values from previous iterations in `activejson` in the "modify properties here" area.) My understanding is that `activejson` points to `j` rather than serving as a copy but `activejson = j.copy()` doesn't appear to do the trick either, nor does `activejson = {}`. What is the correct command/way to empty this variable and pull the template fresh after each iteration? What is the most efficient way to handle this?

Comment: `j.copy()` only does a shallow copy, so you still get problems with nested objects. See [copy.deepcopy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since JSON is usually structured as nested objects, you would need to use `copy.deepcopy`.

```
activejson = copy.deepcopy(j)
```